# How to prepare a Windows pc to run a Touch screen Kiosk Shopping Mall App

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to lock a Windows machine. So the user won't be able to exit the full screen intensionally or by mistake. Also if the application crash, just will display an error page. 
Not the default Windows grey popup window with the "OK" button.

What Im thinking is having a process checking the status of my app. And If the app fails sends a email to the administrator and restart 3 times then if no success shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with WPF.

Set the Window:

```
BorderStyle=None 
Topmost=True
```

For the Application error catching:

Create an **DispatcherUnhandledException** event on App, that will show another fullscreen window to handle the case of the app failure.

To avoid the user exiting it, you can monitor user KeyDown and set event.Handled=true